# Display Windows Task Manager memory usage in MB

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

Does anyome know any hack where we can modify to display memory usage in MB and not in kb in 'windows task manager's processes'

Its not showstopeper but definately a thing I'll like to see.

Comment: For me it shows it already in MB...

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10, after clicking on "More details" (bottom-left), you can switch to the "Details" tab to see the memory usage as a concrete value instead of seeing a percentage.

If it's not showing, you may need to modify the "View" to include the required column.

If it shows the usage in KB, you may use the calculator and divide the value by 1024 to obtain the usage in MB.